# Why when you return this.each, do you have to re-wrap this within jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I apologise if this has already been asked, but I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

I've created a basic plugin shell.

You can find the code here;

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dlhjL

My question is, why do I have to re-wrap this within jQuery again inside of the each function?

When I initialised the method, this is already wrapped within jQuery, e.g. $('p').myPlugin();

Is there anyway to get around this?

B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.each()` gives the callback only a plain DOM element.  So, inside the `.each()` callback, if you want to use a jQuery object, yuo have to create one from the DOM element that it is passed.

The plug-in itself starts with `this` as the host jQuery object which is why you can do `this.each()`, but `.each()` changes `this` to each successive DOM element inside the callback as it iterates through each DOM element in the host jQuery object.

Here's some annotation:

```
(function($) {

  $.fn.myPlugin = function() {

      // "this" here is the incoming jQuery object and thus
      //    you can call this.each() to iterate each item in the jQuery object

      return this.each(function() {

          // "this" here is each successive DOM object in the jQuery object
          //    because of how .each() works.
          // If you want to be able to use a jQuery object here, you have
          //    to create one as this code does

          $(this).css('background', 'red');

      });
  };

}(jQuery));
```

In this particular case, you don't actually need the `.each()` because `.css()` will do the iteration for you on all the DOM elements in the jQuery object.  You could just do this:

```
jQuery.fn.myPlugin = function() {
    return this.css('background', 'red');
}
```

Comment: @User123 - I added an even simpler version.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrapped is all the paragraph elements, whereas within the `.each` callback it doesn't make any sense to operate on all the elements at the same time.

You typically don't need to jQueryify the element being iterated and in this case you could have written

```
return this.css("background-color", "red");
```